# How do I delete any more than 1 specific character in a paragraph while leaving the first apperance?

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word

Edit: [image: tabs eveywhere]

Spaces and tabs everywhere

Goal:

If there's 1 tab or less, check the next paragraph.
If there's 2 or more tabs, leave the first and delete the rest in that paragraph. Check next paragraph.
I want to leave the first paragraph marker so I can turn it into a table with the word in the first column, and the description/definition in the second column.

Attempted Method:

Look at each character in a paragraph and count the tabs. After counting tab characters, if there are more than the desired amount (currently one tab) then replace the first tab in the paragraph with a "^t" (tab character) and then any remaining tabs in that paragraph with "" (nothing, essentially deleting it).

Issues:

The script only sometimes works. It seems to get hung up when there are lines with less than 2 tabs per line.
The other times it'll delete the first tab in a line. The first occurrence should stay while the remainder leave.
The last line of my test word document sometimes isn't touched.
IF I run in repeatedly, it'll delete all tabs in the document except the last one in the last line.

Description:

I am an ugly coder, sorry. I'm self taught with loops, if/thens, and recording and modifying macros. This is not homework, it's so I don't have to manually go through 1,500 documents to format them since people use tabs to align text instead of the ruler bar. Pacman mode (show/hide non-printable characters mode) is very scary looking.

```
    Sub TabFinder()

Dim oPara As Word.Paragraph 'paragraph
Dim var 'a counter for a FOR loop for finding tabs in a paragraph, represents a single character
Dim TabCounter As Long 'how many tabs will be in a paragraph
Dim oChar As Word.Characters 'characters in a paragraph
Dim StartHere As Long 'not currently used - thought I would try and save the location of the first tab to save it
Dim TabsFoundAndReplaced As Long 'how many times the program has replaced a tab in a line
Dim ReplaceText 'first tab will replace with a tab, 2nd and greater tab will be replaced with nothing
Dim ReplaceAmmount As Long 'counter for how many times tabs have been replaced per line
Dim TabsWantedPerLine As Long 'number of tabs we should keep in a line and not replace

TabsWantedPerLine = 1 'desired upper limit of tabs to stay in a line

Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory 'go to the beginning of the document first for find feature

For Each oPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs 'for every paragraph in the document
        TabCounter = 0
        Set oChar = oPara.Range.Characters 'find the number of characters, and set oChar as the total
            For var = 1 To oChar.Count 'for each character do the following
                If oChar(var) <> "" Then 'stops an error
                    Select Case Asc(oChar(var)) 'stops an error
                        Case 9 '9 is tabs   'if there character oChar is a tab, then do the following
                            'If TabCounter = 0 Then StartHere = var 'not used currently, just a thought on how to save the tab with additional coding
                            TabCounter = TabCounter + 1 'counts tabs in the line
                    End Select
                End If
            Next
            If TabCounter > TabsWantedPerLine Then 'if there are more tabs in a paragraph than upper limit, do the following (hopefully deleting any after the desired tabs
                For ReplaceAmmount = 1 To TabCounter 'do this for each of the tabs in the paragraph
                            If ReplaceAmmount <= TabsWantedPerLine Then ReplaceText = "^t" Else ReplaceText = "" 'replaces the 
                            Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
                            Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
                            With Selection.Find
                                .Text = "^t"
                                .Replacement.Text = ReplaceText 'replaces with a "^t" if first go around or "" if >1st go around
                                .Forward = True
                                .Wrap = wdFindStop
                            End With
                            With Selection
                                If .Find.Forward = True Then
                                    .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
                                Else
                                    .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
                                End If
                                .Find.Execute replace:=wdReplaceOne
                                '.Find.Execute
                                Set oChar = oPara.Range.Characters 'since we have replaced some characters in the paragraph
                            End With
                Next ReplaceAmmount
            End If
Next 'for each oPara

End Sub
```

Comment: Please clarify the rules. Do you want to: (a) replace multiple contiguous tabs with a single tab (i.e. Buy^t^tCar^t^tParts^t^t); or (b) if you find more than 1 tab anywhere in a paragraph, then replace (i.e. Buy^tCar Parts^t)

Comment: +1 for "Pacman mode" and a very well asked question :D Can you give a couple sample paragraphs?  I'm assuming what you're trying to do (the short version) is have only one tab at the beginning of each paragraph, whereas right now there may be more than one.

Comment: BTW, my answer may not be 100% correct -- you indicate some conflicting information: first that you want to replace a tab (which is `Chr(9)` with "^t" -- I interpret the replacement as a literal string). If you do want to *leave the first instance of `Chr(9)` intact*, please let me know and I'll modify accordingly.

Comment: @DavidZemens - I was replacing it with "^t" because I'm very green in programming. I wanted to leave the first one alone, but couldn't figure out how to do that. I replaced the first one with a tab instead. If I could figure out a way to do so, I would have loved to do it :-)

I want the first tab to stay in all of it's glory.

Comment: @Blackhawk - You are correct. When I was testing this I had random paragraphs of facerolled text with one tab, more than one tab, and 0 tabs intermixed throughout the document for about 5 rows to try and get a good text document.
*tab* words words
words*tab* words *tab to kill* words
words, no tab
words *tab* *tab to kill* words
*tab*

Comment: ok. Give me a minute and I'll tweak my response.

Comment: Are the tabs always at the beginning of the paragraph or are they sometimes in the middle of text?

Comment: @wayne G. Dunn - I want the first tab of each paragraph to be untouched and stay as is. I want all tabs following the first tab (of that paragraph) to vanish. I had problems of my code extending to other paragraphs before finishing the current paragraph. Sorry for the ambiguity. It does seem that David Zemens, in his awesome knowledge, taken this challenge to heart and is helping. I wouldn't want you to "waste" your time if his code works.

Comment: @DavidZemens - Middle of the text. -- for instance "word _tab1 _tab2 definition of _tab3 the word but they really liked putting extra _tab4 characters to format paragraphs and it's annoying"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try something like this which just uses some simple string functions.

First, iterate the paragraphs by index position (I couldn't make it work with a `For Each oPara` loop).

Capture each paragraph's text in a string variable: `paraText`

Use a `Do ... Loop` construct to replace the tabs with the string `Replace` function.  The replacement text is assigned dynamically using the `IIF` function, which will use `"^t"` if `TabCounter=1` or otherwise use the null string `""`.  This loops until there are no tab characters in the string.

Once the `paraText` string has been thoroughly manipulated, simply assign that string to the `oPara.Range.Text = paraText`:

```
Option Explicit
Sub TabFinder()

Dim oPara As Word.Paragraph 'paragraph
Dim var 'a counter for a FOR loop for finding tabs in a paragraph, represents a single character
Dim TabCounter As Long 'how many tabs will be in a paragraph
Dim TabsWantedPerLine As Long 'number of tabs we should keep in a line and not replace

Dim paraText As String 'represents the string of each paragraph

TabsWantedPerLine = 1 'desired upper limit of tabs to stay in a line

Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory 'go to the beginning of the document first for find feature

For var = 1 To ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count 'for every paragraph in the document
    Set oPara = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(var)
        TabCounter = 0
        paraText = oPara.Range.Text
        '# Loop until there are no more tabs left to replace
        Do Until InStr(paraText, Chr(9)) = 0
            TabCounter = TabCounter + 1
            '# replace tabs in our temporary string variable:
            paraText = Replace(paraText, Chr(9), IIf(TabCounter = 1, "^t", vbNullString), , 1)
        Loop

        '# Assign our new string ot the paragraph range
        oPara.Range.Text = paraText
Next var
End Sub
```

**Updated from comments above**

Backwards iteration over each character in paragraph, delete character **IF** it's a tab **AND** there is another tab somwhere to the *left* of it within the paragraph. This is functionally same as ensuring there is only one tab per paragraph, and only the first one should remain.

Example document:

[image]

Example output:

[image]

Here is the updated code. This would need more (probably a lot more) tweaking if you wanted to allow more than one tab per paragraph, but since the limit is 1, I think this works.

**Note:** This does **not** address *indentation* which Word recognizes distinctly from the paragraph's *text*.

```
Sub TabFinder()

Dim oPara As Word.Paragraph 'paragraph
Dim var 'a counter for a FOR loop for finding tabs in a paragraph, represents a single character
Dim i As Integer

Dim paraText As String 'represents the string of each paragraph

Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory 'go to the beginning of the document first for find feature

LeaveFirstTab = False

For var = 1 To ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count 'for every paragraph in the document
    Set oPara = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(var)
    For i = oPara.Range.Characters.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Mid(oPara.Range.Text, i, 1) = Chr(9) Then
            'As long as there's another tab to the left of this one, delete this one
            If InStr(Left(oPara.Range.Text, i - 1), Chr(9)) > 1 Then
                oPara.Range.Characters(i).Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next

Next

End Sub
```

**Updated to explain Mid() Function**

The VBA `Mid` function takes a substring of specified length, starting at a specified position, from a string. Syntax is:

```
MID( string, start_position, number_of_characters )
```

So in the code above, we are taking the substring beggining at `i` (our character iterator) with a length of `1`. This is basic way to iterate over characters in a string.

I just noticed though that there is a better/simpler way to do this with Word's object model. Instead of the Mid function, I think you can use `oPara.Range.Characters(i)` to return the same substring. I don't know why I didn't realize this earlier because we actually use that method two lines later when we do the `.Delete`!

So modified:

```
   For i = oPara.Range.Characters.Count To 1 Step -1
        If oPara.Range.Characters(i) = Chr(9) Then
            'As long as there's another tab to the left of this one, delete this one
            If InStr(Left(oPara.Range.Text, i - 1), Chr(9)) > 1 Then
                oPara.Range.Characters(i).Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks! I understand everything up until the "If Mid..." portion. Would you be so kind to explain how it works so I can expand my knoweledge?

Comment: Sure! I've updated to include explanation and actually a simpler way to do it without the Mid function :)

Comment: Thanks so much for your assistance. I have a lot to learn and you explaining things have greatly helped me gain some knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

This code makes permanent changes to your data, so test it before using in real life.

This code seems to do what you want.

```
Sub TabFinder()

    Dim i As Long

    Const sFAKETAB As String = "|tab|"

    For i = 1 To ThisDocument.Paragraphs.Count
        'replace the first tab w a fake one
        ThisDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text = Replace(ThisDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text, vbTab, sFAKETAB, 1, 1)
        'replace all other tabs w nothing
        ThisDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text = Replace(ThisDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text, vbTab, vbNullString)
        'replace the fake tab w a real tab
        ThisDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text = Replace(ThisDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text, sFAKETAB, vbTab)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Here's the thing about using a For Each and changing the .Range.Text property: it doesn't work. It seems to reset which paragraph it's on. Kind of like when you delete something in a For Each loop and VBA loses track of where it is. So the above line are a little more verbose than 1) using For Each 2) using a With Block and/or 3) setting an object variable, but it works.

**Update**
Or you can replace the tabs with spaces, per Wayne's excellent comment.

```
Sub TabFinder3()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    Const sFAKETAB As String = "|tab|"
    Const lMAXTABS As Long = 5 'the maximum adjacent tabs you would have

    For i = 1 To ThisDocument.Paragraphs.Count
        'replace the first tab a fake one
        ThisDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text = Replace(ThisDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text, vbTab, sFAKETAB, 1, 1)
        'replace all other tabs w a space - multiple tabs replace wWith one space
        For j = lMAXTABS To 1 Step -1
            ThisDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text = Replace(ThisDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text, String(j, vbTab), Space(1))
        Next j
        'replace the fake tab w a real tab
        ThisDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text = Replace(ThisDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text, sFAKETAB, vbTab)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't get this one to work quite right. I really am greatful that you put effort into this. @david has given me a working chuck of code that does the job and so I've marked him as the answer.

Comment: The above code works fine for removing all but the first tab. However, if you had tabs between words, the words now run together (i.e. 'Now^tis^the^ttime' becomes 'Now^tisthetime'. Which can be easily fixed by inserting a space or whatever you need. Is that what you mean when you say it didn't work?